# Per-thread allocator instance

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, thread-safety

Some background for this question may be helpful: I have multithreaded application written in C++, in which memory management is critical point in terms of performance. I have already 'main' allocator implemented, let's assume it's called 'ManagedAllocator'. I have also my own, multi-platform thread local storage support, written in `asm` using `fs` CPU register. So basically, now my global operator new looks like this:

```
void* operator new(Size_t memSize)
{
  Thread_data& tls = get_thread_local_data();
  ManagedAllocator* allocator = tls[TLS_INDEX_MANAGED_ALLOCATOR];
  return allocator->AllocateMemory(memSize);
}
```

Creation and destruction of local instance of allocator is performed by each thread. That works really nice and ultra-fast, compared to standard allocators (already tested on Win7/8, Linux, MacOS and WP8 (for which implementation of TLS is sligthly different).

Now, the problem:
I have following class:

```
template < Size_t Alloc_size >
class FixedPoolAllocator
{
};
```

This class was used internally by ManagedAllocator, but recently it turned out that I will need to use it also as a standalone allocator. I cannot, however, do it the same way as with ManagedAllocator, because I would need to use one slot in TLS array for **each specialization** of FixedPoolAllocator.

I do not want, however, to play with locks, because the whole thing is to have lock-free allocations. Is there a way to do this in a clean, elegant way?

---

*** UPDATE ***

---

I forgot to mention one thing: what I really need to do.

I have simple class:

```
template < class Allocator >
class EXS_INTERFACE CustomAllocObject
{
public:
  explicit CustomAllocObject();
  ~CustomAllocObject();

  static void* operator new(Size_t memSize);
  //also new[], placement versions, etc.

  static void operator delete(void* memPtr);
  //same as above
};
```

which simply does:

```
template < class Allocator >
_EXSTemplateDef void*
CustomAllocObject<Allocator>::operator new(Size_t memSize)
{
  return Allocator::AllocateMemory(memSize);
}
```

I use this to create objects that need fast allocation:

```
class Image : public CustomAllocObject< FixedSizeAllocator<sizeof(ImageInternal)> >
{
};
```

AllocateMemory() is static function in each allocator class. So perfect solution would be:

```
template < Size_t Alloc_size >
_EXSTemplateDef void*
FixedPoolAllocator<Alloc_size>::AllocateMemory(Size_t memSize)
{
  FixedPoolAllocator<Alloc_size>* alloc = get_somehow_this_threads_instance();
  return alloc->PerformAllocation();
}
```

The problem is, I cannot do this:

```
template < Size_t Alloc_size >
class FixedPoolAllocator
{
  //....
  static EXS_THREAD_LOCAL FixedPoolAllocator<Alloc_size> _local_instance;
};
```

because library is compiled to DLL. FixedPoolAllocator is DLL_EXPORT class in this case (which means all it's static members also are) and DLL_EXPORTed THREAD_LOCALs are not allowed.

Comment: Why don't you use `thread_local` ?

Comment: I updated question to explain why thread_local (aka __thread or __declspec(thread)) is not a solution.

Comment: I don't know about `__declspec(thread)` but gccs `__thread` is actually a bit different than the c++ `thread_local` keyword. But if your implementation does not support that keyword, well...

Comment: You misundestood my explanation: EXS_THREAD_LOCAL is defined as __thread on gcc, __declspec(thread) on MSVC, etc. Read last 2 lines of my question - the problem is, that library is compiled to DLL.

Comment: As I said, `__thread` and `thread_local` are not the same on gcc, and I don't know about `__declspec(thread)` but I would assume that it is not the same as `thread_local` as `thread_local` is nowhere defined to not work within dlls. But when your implementation does not (fully) support `thread_local`, its worthless talking about it, but if it does, you should try that instead.